# Devise and ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise, mass-assignment

I am working on the registration process via devise

I try to save "payments" to a "user" which registers via a formular.
When User choose "bank" from a checkbox, a depending Payment should be also created to the User.

```
<!-- language: ruby -->
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name

  attr_accessible :payments_attributes
  # also tried attr_accessible :payments_attributes, :payments
  has_many :payments, :autosave => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments, allow_destroy: false

end


class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :method, :paid
  attr_accessor :method, :paid

  belongs_to :user

end

new.html.erb

  <%= f.fields_for :payment do |payment| %>
        <div>
          <%= payment.radio_button(:method, 'bank') %>
          <%= payment.label :bank_transfer %>
          <%= payment.radio_button(:method, 'paypal') %>
          <%= payment.label :paypal %>
        </div>
    <% end %>



These are the attributes I wanna set:

my_attributes = {"first_name"=>"Max", "last_name"=>"Mustermann", "password"=>"12345678", "password_confirmation"=>"12345678", "email"=>"max@mustermann.at", "company"=>"ACME INC", "industry"=>{"title"=>"Metall", "oenace"=>"123"}, "payments"=>{"method"=>"bank_transfer", "paid"=>"false"}}

User.new(my_attributes)
# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: payments
```

I also tried to add this to the user model:

```
  def after_initialize
    self.payments.build if self.payments.blank?
  end
```

Any ideas or suggestions why these params not being saved?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign payments instead of payments_attributes. If this is being returned by fields_for in a view, it is most likely caused by lack of `accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments` inside your User model.

UPDATE:

you missed 's' in name of your association passed to `fields_for`. Should be

```
fields_for :payments  do |payment|
```

Comment: sorry copy/paste error: I have these in my model set:   ```accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments, allow_destroy: false```

Comment: Could you add your form code as well then? `fields_for` does not do what you would expect, so probably the error is there.

Comment: hm when I change :payment to payments: in my devise/registrations/new.html.erb the whole part of f.fields_for will not be rendered.

Comment: Because you have no payments for given model. In your controller add sth like `@user.payments.build`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41185/discussion-between-jan-and-broisatse)

Comment: Is it not possible to swap all the given data to with one create, bypassing the "@user.payments.build"?
example: ```
User.create!({name: "John", payments: {paid:true, method: "bank"} } ) ```

Comment: It needs to be `payments_attributes: {}`, not `payment: {}`